# cuando el input y/o el select no tenga ningún valor que aparezcan de algún color - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

cuando el input y/o select no tengan ningún valor seleccionado o escrito que aparezcan de algún color así sea una sombra con color.

```js
import React from 'react'

function Pruebas() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input uno" />
        <select>
          <option value="uno">uno</option>
          <option value="uno">dos</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pruebas
```

Comment: Hola, ¿eso es lo que has probado?

Comment: he intentado añadirle un estado pero no he podido..

Comment: alguien que me pueda colaborar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad style para aplicar css según si el input tiene valor o no

```
function Pruebas() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState();
  const [select, setSelect] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="input uno"
          style={{ "background-color": !input && "gray" }}
          value={input}
          onChange={({ target }) => setInput(target.value)}
        />
        <select
          style={{ "background-color": !select && "gray" }}
          onChange={({ target }) => setSelect(target.value)}
        >
          <option value="">seleccionar</option>
          <option value="uno">uno</option>
          <option value="uno">dos</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```